# Orbit Space question

Tags: general-topology

So I'm wondering how I would show that the orbit space $I^2/D_4$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$ and $\Delta XYZ$ where X is the origin, Y is a vertex of $I^2$ and Z is the midpoint of an edge of $I^2$. I suppose I'm just confused about what I need to demonstrate here. I already know that $XYZ$ is the fundamental domain.